# Is PyOpenGL a good place to start learning opengl programming?

Tags: python, graphics, pyopengl

I want to start learning OpenGL but I don't really want to have to learn another language to do it. I already am pretty proficient in python and enjoy the language. I just want to know how close it is to the regular api? Will I be able to pretty easily follow tutorials and books without too much trouble?

I know C++ gives better performance, but for just learning can I go wrong with PyOpenGL?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

With the caveat that I have done very little OpenGL programming myself, I believe that for the purposes of learning, PyOpenGL is a good choice.  The main reason is that PyOpenGL, like most other OpenGL wrappers, is just that: a thin wrapper around the OpenGL API.

One large benefit of PyOpenGL is that while in C you have to worry about calling the proper `glVertex3{dfiX}` command, Python allows you to just write `glVertex3(x,y,z)` without worrying about telling Python what type of argument you passed in.  That might not sound like a big deal, but it's often much simpler to use Python's duck-typing instead of being overly concerned with static typing.

The OpenGL methods are almost completely all wrapped into Python methods, so while you'll be writing in Python, the algorithms and method calls you'll use are identical to writing OpenGL in any other language.  But since you're writing in Python, you'll have many fewer opportunities to make "silly" mistakes with proper pointer usage, memory management, etc. that would just eat up your time if you were to study the API in C or C++, for instance.

Comment: Same can be said about JOGL for Java fans.

Answer (score 0):

> PyOpenGL

I don't think it is a good choice. *In my opinon* in C/C++ it is easier to play around around with your OpenGL code - start with simple app, then add shader, then add some geometry functions, make a texture/geometry generator, build scene via CSG, etc. You know - to have fun, play around with code, experiment and learn something in process. I honestly just don't see myself doing this in python. Surely it is possible to do OpenGL programming in Python, but I see no reason to actually do it. Plus several OpenGL functions take memory pointers as arguments, and although there probably a class (or dozen of alternatives) for that case, I don't see a reason to use them when a traditional way of doing things is available in C/C++, especially when I think about amount of wrappers python code uses to pass vector or array of those into OpenGL function. It just looks like making things more complicated without a real reason to do that. Plus there is a noticeable performance drop, especially when you use "RAW" OpenGL.

Besides, if you're going to make games, it is very likely that you'll have to use C++ or some other "non-python" language.

P.S. I've done enough OpenGL programming, a lot of DirectX programming, but I specialize on C++, and use python only for certain algorithmic tests, tools and scripts.

Comment: Hey. I marked you down because in my opinion this isn't good advice. I thought I'd leave a comment explaining why instead of doing it anonymously and leaving no feedback. You say you think it's easier in C++, but don't say why. The Python code is shorter and simpler, requiring fewer parameters and less thinking.

Comment: ...I spent 7 years writing C and C++, but the Python equivalent would be just the same as the C/C++ version, but slightly easier to create because, as Mark Rushakoff says, there are no pointer or memory management issues to deal with. PyOpenGL will automatically wrap all OpenGL function calls with parameter checking and error checking by default, making diagnosis easier. Using PyOpenGL you can pass a vertex array as an ordinary Python list - there are no wrappers. There are performance implications, but not complexity issues.

Comment: Plus, I know many people who make games using Python. Your assumption that this requires C/C++ is based on your assumption that OpenGL is bad in Python, which is based on your assumption that making games must require C/C++... :-)

Comment: @JonathanHartley Does the library help developers avoid the problems of dynamic typing? As in, preventing you from doing something dumb like having autocomplete accidentally fill in an integer array for a float argument.

Comment: @Water. You can pass in almost any types (e.g.an array of contiguous C floats, or a Python list of ints, etc) and PyOpenGL will silently convert the sequence of numbers into something that OpenGL can use. This is good for getting started, so that you can see something working without having to stress too much about types too much. (e.g. maybe you are getting the array from somewhere else, e.g. the output of a NumPy calculation, so have little control over its type.) But then later you can set a flag OpenGL.ERROR_ON_COPY to raise errors instead of doing these conversions.